# Cannot run powershell scripts unless I run as administrator

Tags: powershell

I have set-executionpolicy unrestricted.  I was able to run scripts previously.  After I got an error running a powershell script, I started getting the following error:

File C:..\test.ps1 cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by
software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy.

It doesn't matter what is in the script file I am trying to run.

From what I can tell nothing else has changed.  I was doing something with a remote powershell session to a remote machine, got an error.  Then was unable to run scripts locally unless I run powershell.exe as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software Restriction Policies (SRP) have nothing to do with Powershell directly.

Someone has set a restriction on what can be run and/or from where it can be run.

This isn't related to Powershell Execution Policy, Powershell Remoting, nor administrative rights/privileges.

Typically SRP is set through Group Policy and pushed out (I'm guessing you're on a domain).

You could use `rsop.msc` on your machine to try to determine what the settings are and maybe which policy is applying them.

If you want more information on SRP you should probably post on [ServerFault](http://www.serverfault.com).